# Scala case classes order in same file matters

Tags: scala, playframework-2.1

I have one scala file that contains two case classes. ContactInfo is part of Profile. If I put ContactInfo case class after Profile case class, two compile exceptions will be thrown. Why the order of classes matters? If I move ContactInfo before Profile, the error is gone.

```
[error] No Json deserializer found for type Option[models.ContactInfo]. Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type.
[error]         "contactInfo" -> p.contactInfo

[error] No Json deserializer found for type models.ContactInfo. Try to implement an implicit Reads or Format for this type.
[error]     (__ \ 'contactInfo).readNullable[ContactInfo]




case class Profile(
  id: ObjectId = new ObjectId,
  contactInfo: Option[ContactInfo] = None
)

object Profile extends ProfileJson

trait ProfileJson {

  implicit val profileJsonWrite = new Writes[Profile] {
    def writes(p: Profile): JsValue = {
      Json.obj(
        "id" -> p.id,
        "contactInfo" -> p.contactInfo
      )
    }
  }
  implicit val profileJsonRead = (
    (__ \ 'id).read[ObjectId] ~
    (__ \ 'contactInfo).readNullable[ContactInfo]
  )(Profile.apply _)
}

case class ContactInfo(
  givenName: String
)

object ContactInfo {
  implicit val contactInfoJsonWrite = new Writes[ContactInfo] {
    def writes(a: ContactInfo): JsValue = {
      Json.obj(
        "givenName" -> a.givenName
      )
    }
  }

  implicit val contactInfoJsonRead = (
    (__ \ 'givenName).read[String]
  )(ContactInfo.apply _)
}
```

Comment: By your code, "ContactInfo is sub-class of Profile" statement is not true.

Comment: Can the error be fixed by adding the types of the implicits explicitly?

Comment: The error can be fixed if I move ContactInfo before Profile class.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the ordering of the classes is the problem. I think the rules for implicitly finding them is your problem. Try to change the ordering of the companion objects.

Comment: Could you explain further or give some example what is implicit finding?